# + and - quantity is calculated after mouse click Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Currently i can input a value into a number box and it would calculate the quantity * Price, into a subtotal field.
I'm having an issue where i would like the subtotal calculated after i click on (+) and (-) buttons. 
what is happening is after i click the button it wont calculate the number in the quantity box, only the previous number that was there.
i.e- when i click (+) it will display 1 in the quantity field, but subtotal wont change. i click (+) again the quantity will display 2, but the subtotal will display $99 which is the price of a single product. it should be displaying $198.

```js
var total_items = 1;
    function CalculateItemsValue() {
    var total = 0;

    for (i=1; i<=total_items; i++) {
         
        itemID = document.getElementById("qnt_"+i);
        if (typeof itemID === 'undefined' || itemID === null) {
            alert("No such item - " + "qnt_"+i);
        } else {
            total = total + parseInt(itemID.value) * parseInt(itemID.getAttribute("data-price"));
        }
        }
         
    
    document.getElementById("ItemsTotal").innerHTML = "$" + total;
     }
```

```html
<input type="button" value="-" class="qtyminus" field="qnt_1" onmouseup="CalculateItemsValue()">
<input type="number" name="qnt_1" id="qnt_1" value="0" class="qty" data-price="99.95" onkeyup="CalculateItemsValue()" oninput="validity.valid||(value='');">
<input type="button" value="+" class="qtyplus" field="qnt_1" onmouseup="CalculateItemsValue()">
<div id="ItemsTotal">$0</div>
```

Comment: See the error in the console? (that's not your issue, somebody made it a runnable snippet without adding a ItemsTotal element :p )

Comment: By the way, you are not changing the value of the input at all, so it'll remain at 0 forever

Comment: Use 'onchange' rather than 'onmouseup'. That way you'll get called after the value has changed.

Comment: @JaromandaX I made the edit, but that element wasn't there to begin with.

Comment: I know @ScottMarcus - the fault lies with the OP :p

Comment: @pbuck Use `input`, rather than `change`. `change` requires you to leave the field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't include any HTML for the `ItemsTotal`.

This is a lot simpler than what you are doing.  The key is setting up the correct event handlers. You have 2 buttons and the input, so 3 ways that the quantity could be changed. So, you need to set up 3 event handlers. But, don't do the event handling in the HTML, do it in the JavaScript (more on that below).

A couple of notes:

- Don't use inline HTML event handling attributes (`onclick`, etc.). There are **[many reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43459890/javascript-function-doesnt-work-when-link-is-clicked/43459991#43459991)** why you should not use this ancient technique.
- Don't use `.innerHTML` unless the string you are setting has HTML in it. Otherwise, you are just asking the browser to parse HTML when there isn't any. Use `.textContent` for strings that have no HTML in them.
- `parseInt()` isn't necessary on an `input type="number"` since only numbers can be entered. All you need to do to convert the value is prepend a `+` on to the value.
- We can do **[currency formatting with JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString)**, so no need to concatenate `$` into the result of your math.

See the comments for explanations:

```js
// Get references to DOM elements:
var minusBtn = document.querySelector(".qtyminus");
var plusBtn = document.querySelector(".qtyplus");
var input = document.getElementById("qnt_1");
var total = document.getElementById("total");

// Get the data-price and convert to a number
var price = +input.dataset.price;

// Set up event handlers that call a common function with an 
// argument that specifies what kind of operation to perform:
minusBtn.addEventListener("click", function() { calc("subtract"); });
plusBtn.addEventListener("click", function() { calc("add"); });
input.addEventListener("input", calc);

// Single function to perform all calculations
// dependant on the argument pased
function calc(operation) {
  if(operation === "add"){
     input.value = +input.value + 1;
  } else  if(operation === "subtract"){
     // Set value, but don't let it go below zero
     input.value = (input.value - 1 < 1) ? 0 : input.value -1;    
  }
  
  // Update the total no matter what and format the result
  // in the US currency format
  total.textContent = (input.value * price).toLocaleString("en-us", { style: "currency", currency: "USD" });
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="-" class="qtyminus" field="qnt_1">
<input type="number" name="qnt_1" id="qnt_1" min="0" value="0" class="qty" data-price="99.95">
<input type="button" value="+" class="qtyplus" field="qnt_1">
<div>Your total is: <span id="total"></span></div>
```

Comment: This will work fine if there is only one of these widgets per page.  It could easily be modified to handle multiple widgets.

Comment: @James That was never a requirement stated in the question.

Comment: Not in the question but in the code.  `for (i=1; i<=total_items; i++)`  If total_items == 1 then your solution is great.

Comment: @James ?? What is it you are trying to say? I thin the solution is pretty great already.

Comment: Thank you Scott for the detailed explanation. I appreciate it.

Comment: if i wanted to take this a step further and have the span sent into the submitted form. how would i do this?

Comment: @Juniortear You can't include a `span`s data in a form's submit, but you can create an `<input type='hidden' name="totalPrice">` and then add one more line to the code I've already shown: `document.querySelector('input[type=hidden]').value = total.textContent`. Then, when you submit the form, the hidden form field will submit its data.